# Passing an Object On-Click Through a Service to Another Controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-services

what I'm trying to do is use ng-click to pass in the current object in ng-repeat to a controller function.

```
<div ng-controller="ScheduleCtrl as vm" >               
<div ng-repeat="item in vm.items">   
<div ng-click="vm.select(item)">
```

The first controller is registered, dependent on the service, and defined as follows with the method referred to above.

```
var app = angular.module('ascensionApp');
app.controller("ScheduleCtrl", ["$scope", 'ScheduleService', 

function(ScheduleService) {
    var vm = this; 
vm.select = function(scheduleItem){
            ScheduleService.save(scheduleItem);
        };
}]);
```

The service is registered to the module, and defined as follows with the save method to accept the incoming object into scope, and a method to return the object.

```
app.service('ScheduleService', function() {

var scheduleItem = {};


this.save = function(scheduleItem){
    scheduleItem.pop();
    scheduleItem.push(scheduleItem);
};

this.show = function(){
    return scheduleItem;
};
});
```

The controller for a separate element attempts to access the data.

```
app.controller("DashboardCtrl", ["$scope", 'ScheduleService', function($scope, ScheduleService) {
    $scope.data = ScheduleService.show();
}]);
```

It would then be displayed on the view like follows:

```
<div id="dashboard" ng-controller="DashboardCtrl">
<h1 class="mdl-card__title-text" id="headline">
                        It's time for {{data.name}} 
</h1>
```

I'm new to Angular, but have been researching using custom services all day. Right now I am getting the error that:

ScheduleService.save is not a function

I've tried many variations of creating Service methods but either do not get any success or the error above. Can someone please explain what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ScheduleService` is undefined b/c of an error in your controller.

When you declare a controller and specify the the names of things to inject, the controller function must have those same dependencies listed as function arguments in the same order, like this:

```
app.controller("ScheduleCtrl", ["$scope", 'ScheduleService', 

function($scope, ScheduleService) {
```

Comment: Hey, Thank you for reminding me of that! After a little tweaking the methods started working. I had to use $rootscope and broadcast an event to my second controller inside the first controller's method, in order to get it to update on the second controller area.